# Firefox WebExtension API "downloads" not working

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to create my own extension, which automatically downloads files from certain websites and saves it in the default downloads folder. I started with the ["your first extension"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension) example that creates a red border around the page. This worked!

Then I tried to use [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download), which explains the download function, to download an image from google server and it just won't work. I also added a permission for "downloads" API in the manifest.json, but it does not help. The code breaks and everything after `browser.downloads.download` is not executed.

I also tried `console.log(browser);` and `console.log(browser.downloads);`. The `browser` object is defined, but `browser.downloads` is undefined.

Here is the code:

manifest.json:

```
{

"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Permission Test",
"version": "1.0",

"description": "Downloads an image",

"applications": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "permission@example.com"
    }
},

"icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
},

"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "downloads"
],

"content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": ["*://www.google.de/logos/doodles/2018/*"],
    "js": ["script.js"]
    }
]

}
```

script.js:

```
document.body.style.border = "10px solid red";
console.log('Extension started.');


function onStartedDownload(id) {
    console.log('Started downloading: ${id}');
}

function onFailed(error) {
    console.log('Download failed: ${error}');
}

var downloadUrl = "https://www.google.de/logos/doodles/2018/virginia-woolfs-136th-birthday-5857012284915712.6-l.png";

console.log(browser.downloads);

var downloading = browser.downloads.download({
    url: downloadUrl
    //filename: 'my-image-again.gif',
    conflictAction: 'uniquify'
});

downloading.then(onStartedDownload, onFailed);

console.log('Extension execution finished.');
```

I am using Firefox 58 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `downloads` API is not available in content scripts, you probably want to move that code to a background page.  I would start by reading this page to familiarize yourself with the overall structure of WebExtensions:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I have now a bit of progress.This page about [Communicating with background scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_background_scripts) helped as well.